# Deleting file locks in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, cursor

I did not realize that I should have been deleting cursors after accessing attribute tables until today. Up until now I never did this, but I've noticed that there are lots of file locks after my script runs (I presume it was a bad practice on my part to begin with). [ArcGIS 10 help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003m000000.htm) tells me that I should use the following code:

```
# Delete cursor and row objects to remove locks on the data 
# 
del row 
del rows
```

I'm doing that in the following function:

```
# calculate areas
def area_calc( shapefile ):
    "calculates geometric properties of each building"      

    # loop through attribute table    
    Rows = ARCPY.UpdateCursor( shapefile ) 

    for row in Rows:

        geom = row.Shape

        polyArea = geom.area
        row.setValue( perimName, 0 )  # set to zero
        polyPerim = geom.length

        row.setValue( areaName, polyArea )   # update area value
        row.setValue( perimName, polyPerim ) # update perimeter value       

        Rows.updateRow(row)   

    # Delete the row and cursor    
    del row 
    del Rows

    ARCPY.AddMessage( 'Area and Perimeter calculated for each polygon' )
```

However, when I do that I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LoopModuleBuildingAnalysis.py", line 9, in <module>
    import ConstructionMaterialPhase1
  File "D:\Code\AnalysisPhase1.py", line 101
    del row
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any suggestions what I should be doing?

Comment: Does 'del row' need to be indented one stop?

Comment: I don't think so - the help file does not do this, and it makes sense (to me) that it should be after the loop completes; though I don't know how `row` is seen later in the program, as it seems to be out of scope.

Comment: Is this a file geodb?  If so, did you try creating a new filegdb, then copying all the contents to the new filegdb.  I wouldn't think locks would get copied.

Comment: It's not a file geodb; I think the problem may have been just the `del row`, though it's still crashing half-way through running and I see locks on earlier files, so I'm not sure....

Comment: Is the code above the actual failing code? A copy/paste of the function above works fine for me.  An indentation problem usually gives a IndentationError not a SyntaxError.

Comment: Yes, it is the failing code. I removed `del rows`, and it works, but it does not appear to delete the locks after running.

Comment: Rows isn't used elsewhere is it? Rows != rows due to case sensitivity.

Comment: In the linked example, `row` is used to iterate through `Rows`

Answer (score 5):

Deleting an unbound name will raise NameError, not SyntaxError. The following code, roughly equivalent, runs fine

```
>>> def foo():
...     for x in range(0, 5):
...         print x
...     
...     del x
... 
>>> foo()
0
1
2
3
4
```

Check to see that your for block is indented properly and that you don't have any wacky mix of tabs and spaces.

Comment: I think the problem was with the spacing in the help file that I copied. However, I'm a little confused - is it necessary to delete `row`? It just exists within the loop as far as I can tell - I suppose it could be deleted on every loop iteration, but that seems inefficient.